# Auto-mapper 3.2 throw error with Entity Framework core 2.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am working on .NET CORE application with Entity Framework Core 2.0 and automapper 3.2.0, recently updated Entity Framework Core from 2.0 to 2.1.2 and start getting an error for automapper.

[image]

I wonder if I need to update any other package along with that or entity framework core 2.1.2 is compatible with Automapper 3.2.0.

Comment: The only supported version in some sense of the word is the latest. Any version older than 5.0 is very different than the latest. I know that doesn't answer your question, but it might give you an idea :)

Comment: Automapper seems to be very old, You can update it by Manage Nuget Package and then check for updates for AutoMapper